# What animals and confections are each of the characters?

Tags: donyatsu

Almost all of the strange creature in Donyatsu all seem to be a hybrid of some confection and some animal.

[image: Ronya, Donyatsu, Bagel]
(From left to right) Ronya, Donyatsu, Bagel

[image: Kumacaroon, Bamucougar, Morudonyatsu, Sakuwabuta]
(From left to right) Kumacaroon, Bamucougar, Morudonyatsu, Sakuwabuta

[image: Menchiwawa, Korokkenn]
(From left to right) Menchiwawa, Korokkenn

What combination of animals and confections are each of the characters listed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of them seems to be [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) which combines the name of some kind of food (reflected in the shape/features of their bodies) and the name or sound made by some animal (reflected in the shape/features of their heads).

- ローニャ (ro-nya): [ロールケーキ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD)/[Swiss roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_roll) + ニャ/にゃ ([Onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) for cat)
- どーにゃつ (do-nyatsu): [ドーナツ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%84)/[Donut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doughnut) + ニャ/にゃ (Onomatopoeia for cat)
  The name is written in Hiragana. For comparison purpose, ドーナツ in Hiragana is どーなつ.
- ベーガル (be-garu): [ベーグル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB)/[Bagel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagel) + **(Unknown)**
- クマカロン (kumacaron): クマ（熊）/Bear + [マカロン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3)/[Macaron<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaron)
  <sub><sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with [Macaroon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaroon).</sub>
- バームクーガー (ba-muku-ga-): [バウムクーヘン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A6%E3%83%A0%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%98%E3%83%B3)/[Baumkuchen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumkuchen) + [ピューマ（クーガー<sup>2</sup>）](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E)/[Cougar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar)
  <sub><sup>2</sup> In the [disambiguation page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC_%28%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF%29), クーガー is a different name for ピューマ; ピューマ (Puma) seems to be more commonly used in Japanese.</sub>
- もるどーにゃつ (morudo-nyatsu): Mold/モルド<sup>3</sup> + ドーナツ/Donut + ニャ/にゃ (Onomatopoeia for cat)
  <sub><sup>3</sup> モルド is more of a transcription of the English word "Mold", rather than a loan word.</sub>
- ちくわぶた (chikuwabuta): [ちくわぶ（竹輪麩）<sup>4</sup>](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8F%E3%81%B6)/[Chikuwabu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikuwabu) + ぶた（豚）/Pig
  <sub><sup>4</sup> Not to be confused with [ちくわ（竹輪）](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%B9%E8%BC%AA)/[Chikuwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikuwa). Quoting from Wikipedia page of Chikuwabu: "*Chikuwabu* is often confused with the fish-based *chikuwa*, as they are similar in shape and name and are both common ingredients in *oden*. However, unlike *chikuwa*, *chikuwabu* is rarely eaten on its own."</sub>
- メンチワワ (menchiwawa): [メンチカツ<sup>5</sup>](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%82%AB%E3%83%84)/[Menchi-katsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menchi-katsu) + [チワワ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%83%AF)/[Chihuahua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_%28dog%29)
  <sub><sup>5</sup> I linked to Menchi-katsu (ground meat cutlet), since it resembles the illustration best. メンチ (menchi) is a phonetically modified version of the word "mince" in English.</sub>
- コロッケン (korokken): [コロッケ<sup>6</sup>](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1)/[Korokke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korokke) + ケン（犬）/Dog
  <sub><sup>6</sup> Not to be confused with [クロケット](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88)/[Croquette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croquette), although コロッケ/Korokke is a dish originates from クロケット/Croquette.</sub>

Although not in the pictures in the question, there is also マチュマロ (machumaro), translated as marshmallow mouse, which made an appearance in chapter 3. However, the mice seem to be the only characters in the manga whose bodies don't resemble some kind of food.

- マチュマロ (machumaro): マシュマロ/Marshmallow + チュウ (Onomatopoeia for mouse)

  [image: マチュマロ]
  <sub>Source: http://donyatsu.jp/wp-content/themes/donyatsu/characters/img/characterimg12.gif</sub>

As the story progresses, more characters are introduced:

- ウシフォン (ushifon): ウシ（牛）/Cow + [シフォン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD)/[Chiffon cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiffon_cake)

  [image: ウシフォン]
  <sub>Source: http://www.square-enix.co.jp/magazine/yg/introduction/donyatsu/img/character12.jpg</sub>
- まっちゃん (macchan): [まっちゃ（抹茶）](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8A%B9%E8%8C%B6)/[Matcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matcha)
  According to the official website, it seems to be a Matcha Donut Cat.

  [image: まっちゃん]
  <sub>Source: http://donyatsu.jp/wp-content/themes/donyatsu/characters/img/characterimg8.gif</sub>
- マルモチーター (marumochi-ta-): [まるもち（丸餅）](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A4%85)/[Marumochi *(lit. Round Mochi)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mochi) + [チーター](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC)/[Cheetah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheetah)

  [image: マルモチーター]
  <sub>Source: http://www.square-enix.co.jp/magazine/yg/introduction/donyatsu/img/character16.jpg</sub>

  Marumochi is grilled before consumption, as seen in the picture below:

  [image: Grilled Marumochi]
  <sub>Source: http://www.ic-net.or.jp/home/ds-chizu/graphic/marumochimein2.jpg)</sub>
  This explains the square pattern on its body.

Comment: It looks like もるどーにゃつ is mold + nyatsu for a [moldy donut cat](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlYmf.jpg). I'm pretty sure Bagel is just a bagel with a cat body.

Comment: @Krazer: The interesting thing is that it is "Begal" in Japanese. Not sure if part of it is name of some type of cat.

Comment: Since "be-garu" is written in katakana, it implies that the word is foreign (or at least foreign sounding). The closest thing the would make sense were would probably be "Bengal," but [he](http://i.stack.imgur.com/btiMR.jpg) doesn't havs the characteristics of a [bengal cat](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/BengalCat_Stella.jpg)... he's just a plain [bagel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2NLf9.jpg) cat.

Comment: @Krazer: The observation about Katakana/Hiragana seems to be true for most cases, except for Donut related characters. I think Bengal cat might make sense, since the animal is reflected in the head of the character, while the food type is reflected in the body of the character.